# visual studio 2015 doesn't see my xunit tests

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, xunit.net

trying to add xunit tests to my ASP.NET 5 project, i've added a class library and fill the project.json like this :

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "",
  "authors": [ "" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.1.0-beta2-build2981",
    "xunit.runner.visualstudio": "2.1.0-beta2-build1055"
  },
  "commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.visualstudio"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-22816",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-22816"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But Visual Studio doesn't recognize any of my unit tests in test explorer :

```
public class Class1
{
    [Fact]
    public void PassingTest()
    {
        Assert.Equal(4, Add(2, 2));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void FailingTest()
    {
        Assert.Equal(5, Add(2, 2));
    }

    int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: What VS versions are you using and what runtime (DNX/KRE)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On another computer, this is working http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html

Maybe installation problem... Thanks to agua from mars anyway

Comment: the linked documentation is not available. The answer is too generic to be useful and did not help me.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem today. This solution works for me:

```
"dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.1.0-beta3-*",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-beta3-*",
    "xunit.runner.visualstudio": "2.1.0",
    "xunit.runners": "2.0.0"
  },
"commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
  },
```

I hope this help you. I had to install 3 nuget package: xunit, xunit.runner.visualstudio and xunit.runners

Comment: It took me ages (in fact until I reread [the documentation](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html)) to spot the "commands" line you use. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Using aspnet runner beta4 works for me:
**project.json**

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "xunit.runner.aspnet": "2.0.0-beta4"
    },
    "commands": {
        "test": "xunit.runner.aspnet"
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: doesn't apper in intellisense :(

Comment: doesn't work for me, even with the latest 2.1.0-beta1-build60 ; i've tryed in test project and in webapp project ...

Comment: Do you use the latest VS 2015 RC ? Do you have log in the test console ?

Comment: yes, latest. Trace is : Unable to start Microsoft.Framework.TestHost

Comment: you should open an issue on GitHub then

Comment: note when i try to use dnx in command line (as I saw on the web), i can't find it ...

Comment: yes, first, dnx is not in the path and second I have a file load exeception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79141/discussion-between-agua-from-mars-and-tim).

Answer (score 0):

You should try a stable, not beta version of xunit library.